# Firebase HTTP function accessing userID?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Couple of questions about firebase functions.

I have a function that needs to verify that the current user is authenticated, and then use their userId to store some data and associate it to them.

- How do i access userId and validate auth in the functions?
- Where can i get the token that needs to be sent to server through http header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get started, look at the official [sample code](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authorized-https-endpoint) available in GitHub that shows how to protect an endpoint.  You'll see that it takes a token from Firebase Authentication for the currently authenticated [user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/User) using [getIdTokenWithCompletion](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/User#-gettokenwithcompletion).  The function uses the Firebase Admin SDK to [verify the token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#verifyIdToken).  The result of verification is a [DecodedIdToken](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.DecodedIdToken) object, which contains various properties, including the user's uid.

Comment: Thanks, I can't really test that before I find out how I can access the auth token on the iOS client. still looking in the docs with no luck

Comment: Added a link to it.